# Where on the balance sheet do I find these items?

Tags: banking, balance-sheet

I am preparing for an interview for a banking role (on the tech side, but with exposure to business aspects), and have found out some questions I might be asked, wrt to where on the balance sheet the following would appear (or if at all):

- Customer loans / customer mortgages
- Customer cash accounts
- Security accounts for equities / bonds held by customers (do they appear at all??)

If someone knows a decent introductory read for complete balance sheet rookies, that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the annual report from a credit union does a good job of explaining the balance sheet. Because the customers of the credit union are the owners of the credit union the annual report is targeted at beginners.

The key thing to remember is that loans are assets not liabilities, and that deposits are liabilities not assets.